# Automapper exception: unsupported mapping or missing mapping

Tags: automapper

I cannot see what the difference in these two mapping functions are other than one distinctly uses Automapper and one is hand jammed. This mapping doesn't work:

```
   Mapper.CreateMap<AfterArrivalViewModel, UpdateAfterArrivalRequestDao>()
            .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
                       {
                           dest.TableId = Mapper.Map(src, new TableId());
                           dest.Identity = Mapper.Map(src, new Identity());
                           dest.ConditionExistPriorToTransfer = Mapper.Map(src, new ConditionExistPriorToTransfer());
                           dest.DependentMedicalOrSpecialEducationNeed = Mapper.Map(src, new DependentMedicalOrSpecialEducationNeed());
                           dest.IssueCategory = Mapper.Map(src, new IssueCategory());
                           dest.IssueCategory2 = Mapper.Map(src, new IssueCategory2());
                           dest.IssueCategoryDetails = Mapper.Map(src, new IssueCategoryDetails());
                           dest.IssueCategory2Details = Mapper.Map(src, new IssueCategory2Details());
                           dest.Reason = Mapper.Map(src, new ReasonExplanation());
                           dest.EmailAddress = Mapper.Map(src, new CommandPointOfContactEmailAddress());
                           dest.FirstName = Mapper.Map(src, new CommandPointOfContactFirstName());
                           dest.LastName = Mapper.Map(src, new CommandPointOfContactLastName());
                           dest.Commercial = Mapper.Map(src, new CommandPointOfContactPhoneCommercial());
                           dest.Dsn = Mapper.Map(src, new CommandPointOfContactPhoneDsn());
                           dest.Rank = Mapper.Map(src, new CommandPointOfContactRank());
                           dest.PlainLanguageAddress = Mapper.Map(src, new CommandPointOfContactPlainLanguageAddress());
                           dest.ProjectedRotationDate = Mapper.Map(src, new ProjectedRotationDate());
                           dest.MedicalDentalEducationalAnswer = Mapper.Map(src, new MedicalDentalEducationalAnswer());
                           dest.MedicalDentalEducationalExplaination = Mapper.Map(src, new MedicalDentalEducationalExplaination());
                           dest.UicAndNameOfMedicalFacility = Mapper.Map(src, new UicAndNameOfMedicalFacility());
                           dest.LastModifiedBy = Mapper.Map(src, new LastModifiedBy());
                       })
                       //.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.InstantiateListOfSqlParameters())
                       ;
```

I originally had it as a before map but that didn't work either.

This mapping does work:

```
   private IQueryCreationDao AssembleAfterArrivalDao(AfterArrivalViewModel model)
    {
        return new UpdateAfterArrivalRequestDao
        {
            TableId = Mapper.Map(model, new TableId()),
            Identity = Mapper.Map(model, new Identity()),
            ConditionExistPriorToTransfer = Mapper.Map(model, new ConditionExistPriorToTransfer()),
            DependentMedicalOrSpecialEducationNeed = Mapper.Map(model, new DependentMedicalOrSpecialEducationNeed()),
            IssueCategory = Mapper.Map(model, new IssueCategory()),
            IssueCategory2 = Mapper.Map(model, new IssueCategory2()),
            IssueCategoryDetails = Mapper.Map(model, new IssueCategoryDetails()),
            IssueCategory2Details = Mapper.Map(model, new IssueCategory2Details()),
            Reason = Mapper.Map(model, new ReasonExplanation()),
            EmailAddress = Mapper.Map(model, new CommandPointOfContactEmailAddress()),
            FirstName = Mapper.Map(model, new CommandPointOfContactFirstName()),
            LastName = Mapper.Map(model, new CommandPointOfContactLastName()),
            Commercial = Mapper.Map(model, new CommandPointOfContactPhoneCommercial()),
            Dsn = Mapper.Map(model, new CommandPointOfContactPhoneDsn()),
            Rank = Mapper.Map(model, new CommandPointOfContactRank()),
            PlainLanguageAddress = Mapper.Map(model, new CommandPointOfContactPlainLanguageAddress()),
            ProjectedRotationDate = Mapper.Map(model, new ProjectedRotationDate()),
            MedicalDentalEducationalAnswer = Mapper.Map(model, new MedicalDentalEducationalAnswer()),
            MedicalDentalEducationalExplaination = Mapper.Map(model, new MedicalDentalEducationalExplaination()),
            UicAndNameOfMedicalFacility = Mapper.Map(model, new UicAndNameOfMedicalFacility()),
            LastModifiedBy = Mapper.Map(model, new LastModifiedBy()),
        }
        ;
    }
```

Other than one being a private method and the other being an automapper map I cannot see why when I call

```
  Mapper.Map<AfterArrivalViewModel, UpdateAfterArrivalRequestDao>(model);
```

I get an automapper exception but if I call the method it works fine.

Any help on this would be great!!

Comment: You've got a zillion `Mapper.Map` calls. I can hardly imagine they're all defined by `Mapper.CreateMap`. But why do you have these calls in the first place?

Comment: They are all defined in separate mapper profiles. That was my attempt at writing cleaner mappings. I obviously extracted too much. The method however works perfectly but the automapper call doesn't